# Simple XML with Flickr API

Tags: api, simplexml, flickr

I am trying to figure out a way to extract the latitude and longitude from a flickr api XML request using SimpleXML.

I have tried the following SimpleXML php script:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.places.placesForTags&api_key=XXXX&place_type_id=7&tags=Defenders+of+Wildlife&format=rest&auth_token=XXXX-XXXX&api_sig=XXXX");

foreach ($xml->places->place as $item) {

print "<p>";
print $item->latitude;
print ","
print $item->longitude;
print "</p>";
print "<br>";
}
?>
```

And here is the XML Document Tree of the URL API request:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<places total="97">
<place place_id="Ayf3HfhQVrOfB2kB" woeid="1492513" latitude="-18.947" longitude="48.521" place_url="/Madagascar/Toamasina/Andasibe" place_type="locality" place_type_id="7" timezone="Indian/Antananarivo" woe_name="Andasibe" photo_count="63">Andasibe, Toamasina, Madagascar</place>
<place place_id="gTWfoV5WU7jJ3tE" woeid="712142" latitude="39.173" longitude="8.976" place_url="/Italy/Sardinia/Capoterra" place_type="locality" place_type_id="7" timezone="Europe/Rome" woe_name="Capoterra" photo_count="44">Capoterra, Sardinia, Italy</place>
</places>
</rsp>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get just the longitude and latitude printed?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Access attributes like arrays:

```
print $item['latitude'];
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php, example #5